# How to properly store object reference in treemodel?

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm trying to store an object reference in the rows of a treemodel so that I can access and modify the data in the underlying data structure. What would be the proper way to do this? The only way I've found so far to accomplish this is to inherit my data structure nodes from gobject, and then store a gobject column in each row. Is there a more preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model column type of:

```
gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT
```

Can be anything!